# Moon craters. How deep do they get?

Tags: the-moon, crater

Ive always wanted the answer to an specific question as you saw in the title "How deep does the moon craters go". Please leave your answers down below possibly link a good source.

Comment: See these papers: [1](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~robinson/labs/moon_craters.pdf), [2](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~sheridev/labs/CTM.pdf), [3](http://www.springbrookobservatory.com.au/lunar_craters2.htm).

Comment: Now you have some material to write an answer on your own.

Answer (score 4):

According to [NASA](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/03/100304165918.htm), the deepest crater (and the widest) is the South Pole-Aitken basin, almost 1,500 miles (2500 km) across and more than five miles (8 km) deep.

Wikipedia mentions [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_%28lunar_crater%29) at 6.1 km, but [another source](http://www.spacegrant.hawaii.edu/futureflight/ffh2001/MoonFAQs/deepcrat.htm) has the depth of this crater at 8.8 km. Might be different definitions of 'depth', though.
The links provided by Uwe disagree as well, providing a depth of 9864 m for an unnamed crater. These measurements are done via photo analysis, by measuring the length of shadows.

The best source data seems to be the [altitude measurements](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014/cub) done via laser ranging by the [LOLA](https://lola.gsfc.nasa.gov/index.html) instrument on NASA's LRO. I haven't found a summary of findings from these data though.

Comment: The measurement of crater depths by photo analysis is not very precise.